# Is it appropriate to tag someone else's question urgent help needed?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, tags

Should [[Urgent] PHP has encountered an Access Violation at 16B357F9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012727/urgent-php-has-encountered-an-access-violation-at-16b357f9) receive the `urgent-help-needed` tag to reflect the question title?

Or should I take the boring option and explain why "Urgent" isn't helpful in a question title?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not even appropriate to tag your *own* question `urgent-help-needed`.  I'd definitely remove it from the title.

Comment: Ceci n'est pas une pipe.

Comment: @Andrew: En anglais, s'il vous plaît.

Comment: This is not a pipe. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Magritte

Comment: @Neil: Thanks.  I didn't think I'd translated it correctly, but I just wasn't getting the reference.

Comment: @Bill: I thought it'd be more of a hint that it's a specific phrase.

Comment: @Andrew: I didn't think to Google the whole phrase, since I was able to translate most of it on my own.  At least I've learned a little bit of culture today (and how to say "pipe" in French).  :)

Comment: @Bill Ah, but can you pronounce it? If memory serves it is "peep",  and if it doesn't no doubt there will be a flood of corrective comments.

Comment: @Neil: That's a good point.  I guess I've only learned how to *spell* "pipe" in French.  I'm betting it sounds like "peepee."

Comment: It's *peep*, but the *ee* is only a short vocal. Here's the phonetic notation: */pip/*.

Comment: [Roll your *r* s](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rJAw-fuYHk)

Comment: | <-- ceci n'est pas une pipe