# Discussing title: Which fits better?

Tags: discussion, title

[I was posting a discussion on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525038/best-documentation-tool-objective-c-project) with this title: "Xcode: best documentation tool (objective-C project)", that has been changed into "Best documentation tool (objective-C project)" saying that using a tag in the title was not correct. Reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles) discussion I still do not understand why the original title wasn't good, the examples shown in the link appear to me as very similar to my original question, the main tag helps explaining the precise context (I'd like to know what is the tool that best integrates in that IDE for accomplishing some tasks as said in the message body), plus another tag 'objective-C' hasn't been removed.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61055/when-should-we-remove-pseudo-tags-from-a-title. Can you link to the SO question?

Comment: They both suck: asking for the "best" anything on SO is walking a dangerous path. See my edit...

Comment: @Shog9: I saw it and appreciated, maybe you are right about the 'best' part, but the title still misses the point. I've added an update.
@mmyers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525038/what-tools-might-i-use-for-generating-documentation-from-an-xcode-project is the link

Comment: edit it then - my intent was to demonstrate how a title that **summarizes** the question doesn't *need* tag **prefixes**. I'm not really familiar enough with Xcode / eclipse to know quite what you're looking for though.

Answer (score 1):

To quote from [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles/10651#10651):

> To be clear, I think it is fine to
>   duplicate the tags in the title, but
>   only when they can be worked into the
>   titles organically and
>   conversationally.

Comment: so a question with a title like: "Oracle: best way to search over range of values" has to be edited too and not put as a Good title

Comment: @rano: yes, that is not a very good title.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple: your question needs to be found by an expert who knows the answer.  Such an expert finds the questions s/he's interested in by filtering on tags.  Given that the person you need would have already selected the 'xcode' tag as a filter, that expert could conceivably be annoyed by a subject title that contains something s/he already knows about the question.  Making it *less* likely that s/he clicks through and looks at the full question.

Avoid annoying the experts, you won't get a good answer.  But it is up to you, annoying an expert is your prerogative.  This website is owned by its users, not the experts.