# Should we edit titles containing tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should we remove pseudo-tags from a title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61055/when-should-we-remove-pseudo-tags-from-a-title)

Many answers on related questions say that a tag shouldn't be duplicated in the title.s

Often I see tags in titles either "[java] question" or "java: question". 
Should we edit these question and remove the tag from title (adding the tag if necessary)?

Would minor edits considered to be nitpicking?

Answer (score 1):

Editing is a great way to clean up *and* explain to new people how things work. So, please, edit!

(And I would't worry how people who boldly post *with* tags and hence failed to first look around to see how things work, feel about that. I think all will appreciate it after being around for some longer time.)