# What is the rule for removing title prefix that is already in the tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should we remove pseudo-tags from a title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61055/when-should-we-remove-pseudo-tags-from-a-title)

Example suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/164571 (was accepted with 2 accept votes and a reject vote)

I sometimes put prefixes on my own questions and am inclined to add a reject vote, but what is the policy on that. I have seen recommendations both ways in comments.

1. Should prefixes like these be removed?
2. Should additional improvement be required in order to justify an edit?

I just have a personal belief that the title should ask the question. Without the word jQuery, it does not say web page.

Comment: This has been discussed multiple times. Jeff's official position was along the lines of "it's okay to include tags in titles as long as it's done organically."

Comment: If you ask Will/Won't he will emphatically tell you never to include tags in titles.

Comment: @PopularDemand which is not the case in this example.

Comment: Yeah, but it still answers your question. "Pseudotags" are bad and should be removed.

Comment: Comment:  BURN THEM

Comment: Isn't this question its own example?

Comment: @Daniel, not entirely. You can tell I am talking about **editing** if I say **What is the rule for removing title prefix that is already in the tags**. But with **How to completley disable any MOUSE CLICK**, you could be referring to something other than web pages. But adding **jQuery** tells you it is a web page.

Comment: @GraceNote haha. that edit is awesome :-)

Comment: [Your title in original form.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QcUKd.png)  ***Do you see?***  [Your title, changing.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpluY.png)  ***Do you see?***  [Your title, reborn.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7lOxI.png)  ***DO YOU SEE?***

Comment: lol @ಠ_ಠWon't hehe someone didn't like your edit :-P

Comment: To quote Jeff Atwood from the linked question: "To be clear, I think it is fine to duplicate the tags in the title, but **only when they can be worked into the titles organically and conversationally**." In other words, if you think the tag must be stated in the title, incorporate it as a part of the sentence, not some oddly shaped prefix.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Burn them.  BURN THEM.  **BURN THEM.** <sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>with the hatred of a thousand devil suns</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Comment: [Burrrrrrrrrn!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iCeOQ.png)

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't♦, I think you went a little to far with the editing of my original post, and the tiny print, and this large, slightly offensive image.

Answer (score 5):

If the title prefix/suffix mirrors a tag and the title stands on its own without it, I would remove it.

Comment: If the title gets worthless without the tag, then something is wrong with the title.

Answer (score 3):

I think about it this way: if you thought of the tags as indicating a particular "folder" in a filing cabinet, would the question make sense when you find it there or does it need further clarification? Could the title be reduced, by removing tags in this case, and still make sense? If removing a tag from the title, could you move it to a different "folder" (tag) and have it make sense? Ideally, the process of editing the title/tags should end up with the question in the proper "folder" (tags) with a descriptive, non-redundant title.

In this case, the question is tagged appropriately and the tag in the title is redundant.  I'm ok with removing it.

Comment: Yes, it's redundant -- but is redundancy always a bad thing?  I spend more time browsing the front page, which has questions with a wide range of tags, than browsing individual tags.

Comment: @KeithThompson but the tags for a question are visible with it on the front page as well.

Comment: Not only are pseudotags in the title redundant, but I think they are anoying *(to me at least)* when browsing a specific tag. Sometimes when I'm browsing the "android" tag, the question list looks like: *"Android: X"*, *"Android: Y"*, *"[Android] Z"*. It somewhat hinders scanning titles quickly to find a question to answer.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Yes, but they're not *as* visible.  I'm certainly not suggesting that all the tags should always be included in the title, but the redundancy is certainly less annoying on the front page than when browsing a particular tag.  If the tag name flows naturally as part of the title, I'd tend to leave it in.

Comment: @KeithThompson I wouldn't obsess about it if, like the comment on the question say, it's organically part of the title. For example, "How do I do X with jQuery?" is redundant if the question is tagged, jQuery but not worth editing.   "jQuery: how do I do X?" on the other hand is awkward and the use of jQuery there adds nothing.  I'd be okay with removing it in either case, but in the latter case I'd actually be inclined to do something about it.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Oh, I don't obsess about it.  Really.  No, I don't.  *I don't obsess about it*.  **WHO TOLD YOU THAT I OBSESS ABOUT IT???!!!**  *ahem*  8-)}