# Should we approve suggested tags in title removals or mark them as too minor?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Apparently at least [one user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483347/weberc2?tab=activity&sort=revisions) has found it easy to look for tags in titles and remove them to help them grind our their +1000 from suggested edits.

Often neither the original nor the edited version would be consider good titles as per the faq [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).

Shouldn't the suggested edit reflect some thought about what makes a good title rather than just be a edit to remove the tags? Or are tags in titles [so bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116837/148672) that need to be community burniated?

Comment: This is pretty textbook too minor, and most if not all of these should be rejected.  Unfortunately, with the state of the review queue, that isn't happening.

Comment: In my defense, I wasn't even aware of a +1000 from suggested edits. I was just doing it because many of my questions received identical edits. It seemed to be standard operating procedure and something the community valued, so I was working to do my part. I'll follow along here to see what is recommended.

Comment: @weberc2 "too minor" doesn't really apply to users with full edit privilages, just users who need to suggest edits, which is why you were seeing it to your own posts.  That said, even those users are encouraged to make substantial edits instead of minor ones.

Comment: @Servy, Duely noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Approve them if the resulting title is clearly better than the old one.

Reject them if it isn't.

A clear, understandable title without tag prefixes is preferable to one with them, so *as a rule* I wouldn't reject these, **however** often these prefixes go hand-in-hand with other problems, so if those aren't being fixed as well then the editor is just re-arranging deck chairs on the Titanic - wasting your time and blocking anyone who might want to make more useful edits.

And... Do a sanity-check: if a tag is being removed from the title and *isn't already an actual tag on the question* then it should probably be added. I've seen questions where important context is lost by being removed from the title and not added anywhere else.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm adding tags to the tag list when I'm removing them, if they aren't already on there.

Comment: Good man, @weberc2. Something else you might want to consider doing is working "tags" into the title *organically* - where "C#: how to frob widgets?" becomes "How can I frob widgets in C#?" This puts the most important bits of context in bold at the top without clumsily mashing them in front of the actual question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. I appreciate the advice. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was about to speak up about this, when reviewing edits earlier today, I came across [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1157905), and another one, which seemed to get approved pretty quickly, despite the fact that removing the tag-like words from the title made it harder to understand.  Someone else beat me to the punch when I went to roll back the edit.

now, I'm on board with removing the `c#` from `c#:  writing a regex to do stuff`, but sometimes the tag-like word is actually the literary subject of the title, in which case It probably should stay there.

Comment: That's exactly why you can just blacklist the words or remove them with an automatic script; you need a person to ensure removing it makes it better and not worse.

Comment: That title needs a bit of love from a domain expert, because it should really be "Setting a property without using dot syntax", or "Inverting a BOOL property without using dot syntax". And the [iphone] tag needs to be removed.