# Title for questions - delete tag name if included?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

Is there any *recommended* way to title or change the title of questions? If the title mentions tags, should we delete them?

In particular, I just found a question title "[BASH - Howto run function when changing terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525802/bash-how-to-run-function-when-the-terminal-is-resized)" that already contains the tag [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

In this case, should we delete the word *BASH* from the title?

Comment: Yes. Work it in organically if possible.

Comment: There are quite a few questions on Meta about this already... but I upvoted this anyway, because it annoys me how people keep rejecting my suggested edits where I've removed the tag from the title, even though it is consensus, and the rest of the post is fine (body doesn't need editing).

Comment: I'd like to add that the FAQ answer there promotes putting tags in the title, and the "bad examples" are what I'd consider good titles, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @DannyBeckett You might want to read [Should we approve suggested tags in title removals or mark them as too minor?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158228/148672)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter You might want to read [Is editing out tags in titles too minor when there is nothing else wrong with the post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164122/195862)

Comment: @DannyBeckett You get that one of the posts is about editing and the other is about suggested edits which is not the same thing.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter The two go hand in hand. Also, the accepted answer on the link I provided was written by a user with 35k+ rep on Meta.

Comment: When used like that, yes. However, a feature request for automated removal was denied (I think), since there are legitimate ways to use the name of a tag within the wording of a title (not prepending or appending it).

Comment: @DannyBeckett suggested edits have a higher cost then edits which is one of the reasons why you can make a 1 character edit but not a 1 character suggested edit. Also please don't make a appeals to authority. Especially when by that measure (rep) you'd lose. The accepted answer on the question I linked to was by Shog9 and has the #2 rank overall on Meta.Se and is the Community Manager for Stack Exchange. In any case I don't think the advice, make the change if the *resulting title is clearly better than the old one* is that controversial

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Please don't take offense to my (and others') opinion. This is Meta. It's for voicing opinions about SO.

Comment: Wooow just posted it and when I come back see a dozen of comments, upvotes, downvotes and marked as duplicated. This is definitely fast.

Comment: @DannyBeckett I'm not offended I just disagree with you that doing nothing but removing tags makes a title better. For example *How do you get the value from a custom field in a WordPress post?* is probably much better than *Get the value of custom field of post*