# Can we do something about people adding C# in their titles?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, title

Commonly, you see questions that state the problem (in very bad, lowercase Engrish) followed (or proceeded) by (lowercase) "c#". Can we do something about this?

Maybe ban C# from titles? [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) is sufficient to indicate you're working with C#.

It's worth noting that this problem isn't specific to C#. It's just the most common one (from my perspective) at this time. Maybe ban programming languages from being in the title? We don't need "reading xml file php" with a question that screams encoding error. What we need is titles like "Possible encoding error while reading XML file". The tag of [php](/questions/tagged/php) is sufficient to indicate it's for PHP.

Comment: If the language name is included fluently in the natural language of the question, it's perfectly suitable to keep. Having a definite *ban* is not the right way to go, in my opinion.

Comment: @JSteen I'm not suggesting a _total_ ban, but I'm suggesting that we do something about it. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Well, do what then? You've suggested a ban (second paragraph ;), which you obviously aren't comfortable with. So, did you have something else in mind that might actually spark a discussion to begin with? =)

Comment: I guess they just think those who can't _see sharp_ will miss the tag

Comment: @gnat Ouch. That's bad.

Comment: @J.Steen [It's not unprecedented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161398/houston-we-have-a-porblem).

Comment: @CodyGray Never said it wasn't. =)

Comment: @JSteen I _suggested_ banning. I didn't say we _had_ to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Banning words from titles is not the answer. We've [experimented with that already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so), and it's been downright infuriating if not an abject failure.

Besides, there are perfectly legitimate reasons to have "tag" words in a title. Good titles work those words into the question organically. This [has been discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

The only problem is when they tack them uselessly onto the beginning or the end. I can only assume that this practice comes from people emulating the system-generated page titles, to which the name of the most popular tag (well, [basically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title)) is prefixed along with a dash. Like how [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226101/can-i-reliably-turn-a-string-literal-into-a-symbol-name-using-templates-or-fanc), with a good title:

> Can I reliably turn a string literal into a symbol name using templates (or fancy macros)?

becomes

> c++ - Can I reliably turn a string literal into a symbol name using templates (or fancy macros)?

Apparently, [this is done for SEO reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions), although [there is some recent debate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87831/the-new-tagname-this-is-the-real-title-formatting-is-unhelpful) about whether [this is even helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127370/should-we-stop-adding-the-most-popular-tag-to-the-html-title-on-every-se-site).

So if we're stuck with the system-generated titles, **how do we fix this problem? The same way we fix all other problems with post content: edits.** Trusted users can make unlimited edits to posts, and users who still have their editor training wheels on can suggest edits for community approval. These are a great way to remove those pesky tags from titles, and improve the title while you're at it. Not only are you improving the site, you even stand to gain a reputation boost if your suggestions are approved.

There are established community standards for this already that are strongly in favor of removing these title warts:

- [When should we remove pseudo-tags from a title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61055/when-should-we-remove-pseudo-tags-from-a-title)
- [What is the rule for removing title prefix that is already in the tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116771/what-is-the-rule-for-removing-title-prefix-that-is-already-in-the-tags)
- [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)
- [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles)
- [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)